# Graph of $f(x)$ given, find graph of $f(|x|)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, absolute-value

I know the graph of $f(x)=x^2-2x$.

> Google calculator https://www.google.com/#q=graph+of+x%5E2-2x

But how can I find the graph of $f(|x|)=|x|^2-2|x|$? What is the best method to approach here? Also, what's the difference between $f(|x|)$ and $|f(x)|$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

take the graph that is an the right half-plane and reflect it about the $y$-axis to obtain the whole graph.

Indeed if $x\ge 0$ then $f(|x|)=f(x)$ so for $x\ge0$ (the right half-plane) the graph does not change.

If $x<0$ then $-x>0$ and $f(|x|)=f(-x)$, which makes the points $(x,f(-x))$ and $(-x,f(-x))$ to both belong to the graph, and these points are symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Concerning $|f(x)|$ if the original graph of $f(x)$ is above (or on) the $x$-axis, then it remains unchanged. But those points of the original graph that are below the $x$-axis get reflected about the $x$-axis, so they end up in the upper half-plane, and the whole graph of $|f(x)|$ is in the upper half-plane (including possibly the $x$-axis itself).

For $f(|x|)$ you start with $x$, apply $|x|$ and then apply the original $f$. As explained above (and in additional detail in the comments), the result is a graph symmetric about the $y$-axis.

For $|f(x)|$ you start with $x$ and immediately apply the original $f$, but of the result is negative, then you "make it positive" and the point of the graph ends up above the $x$-axis.

Comment: Ahh I see, so based on the definition of f(|x|), depending on whether x >= 0 or x < 0, we can conclude that f(x)=f(-x). This is the consequence of a function being even, hence symmetric to the y-axis.

Comment: the original graph in the left half-plane doesn't count anymore, it corresponded to $x<0$ when we use the original function, but for the modified version we first "make $x$ positive" and only after that we apply the original function. So the modified version has no way to "see" what the original version was doing with negative $x$. Yes $f(|x|)$ becomes an even function. Although it is not only that since $f(-|x|)$ is also even ... but in this case we would take the original graph from the left half-plane and reflect about the $y$-axis to obtain the whole graph.

Comment: @user196434 The pictures might help, here his how WolframAlpha [plots $x^2-x$ and $|x|^2-|x|$](http://tinyurl.com/op3p7f3) and here is a picture [showing $x^2-x$ and $|x^2-x|$](http://tinyurl.com/nklm4ko).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, here is also the [plot of $f(-|x|)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x^2-x%2C%28-abs%28x%29%29^2-%28-abs%28x%29%29%29) it is symmetric to the $y$-axis but reflects the piece of the original graph which was the left half-plane

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: the graph where $x \geq 0$ gets mirrored in the vertical axis.

As for the difference between $f(|x|)$ and $|f(x)|$. Suppose $f(x) = x-4$. Then $f(|0|) = f(0) = -4$ whereas $|f(0)| = |-4| = 4$.